# ClamAV ./configure "configure: error: Your OpenSSL installation is misconfigured or missing"

Tags: software-installation, openssl, clamav

When trying to install ClamAv, after entering `./configure`, it prints a bunch of stuff to the terminal before printing the error message "configure: error: Your OpenSSL installation is misconfigured or missing".

I tried to run `sudo apt install openssl` to see if that might fix it, but alas "openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1)."

What might be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What was wrong with installing [`clamav` package from the *main* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=clamav)? Ubuntu Bionic has fresh version 0.100.2. Why do you think you need to compile it?

Comment: I am newish to linux so I look at this as an opportunity to educate myself on stuff like this.

Comment: You would probably need `libssl-dev` as shown here [ClamAV Development: Satisfying Build Dependencies](http://www.clamav.net/documents/clamav-development)

Comment: libssl-dev is already the newest version as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. If you want to learn how stuff is going compiled then do the following:

1. Enable *Source code* repositories  in *Software & Updates* (or `software-properties-gtk`)

   > [image: Enable Source code repository]
2. After checking this checkbox it should ask about reloading package lists. You should confirm it. If unsure run

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```

   manually.
3. Install all needed tools for compilation

   ```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
4. Get all build-dependencies of `clamav` package

   ```
    sudo apt-get build-dep clamav
   ```
5. And then proceed with `./configure` as you plan to do.

Good stuff to read:

- [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) about APT;
- [`man checkinstall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/checkinstall.8.html) about correct method to install self-compiled stuff.

Comment: Hm... thanks for the help, but `sudo apt-get build-dep clamav` prints  `E:  Unable to find a source package for clamav `

Comment: You should enable source code repositories first. See image above.

Comment: I enabled source code repositories first. With the source code check box in software and updates right? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: After checking this checkbox it should ask about reloading package lists. You should confirm it. If unsure run `sudo apt-get update` manually.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't closed Software and Updates so it hadn't prompted me to reload yet. That did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was building ClamAV on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and had same error.

Problem was resolved by installing:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo apt install libxml2-dev
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Found partial solution on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/987788/openssl-not-found-during-configure)

Some install prerequisites:

https://www.clamav.net/documents/installation-on-debian-and-ubuntu-linux-distributions#Users-and-on-user-privileges